# Goals and Unique Pageview don't match in GA3

Tags: regex, google-analytics, goal-tracking

I created a goal in Google Analytics and I'm using this regex (below) but when analyzing with the unique pages, the result is a little different:

paths:

```
/newshop/available/offers-shop
/newshopLC/available/offers-shop
/newshopLC/available/addons
```

regex used in Goals:

```
\/(newshop|newshopLC)\/available\/(offers-shop|addons)
```

I saw in some forums that the difference could be in the Page Title but we use a SPA shopping flow and we don't have a title in any pageview step. I believe the regex is incorrect somehow...

I have tried to change the regex but the difference persist. Maybe I'm doing something wrong...

Comment: The regex you posted has a space at the end - is this intentional? Otherwise it appears to be correct. Though you could simplify it slightly by using `\/newshop(LC)?`

Comment: thanks for returning the question! The space definitely was a typo here, my bad. I'll try your suggestion and see what happens... thanks!